# Opening files in C in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    int i=0;
    int number =0;
    float vector[100];
    float sum=0., mean = 9., stdev=0.;
    FILE *fp_in = NULL;

    fp_in = fopen("stat_data.txt","r");

    if(fp_in != NULL)
    {
        fscanf(fp_in,"%d",&number);
        for (i=0; i < number; i++) 
        {
            fscanf(fp_in, "%f", &vector[i]);
            sum += vector[i];
        }
        mean = sum/number;
        printf("Mean = %f\n",mean);

        sum=0.0;
        for(i=0; i<number;i++)
        {
            sum+= pow(vector[i]-mean,2);
        }

        stdev = sqrt(sum/(number - 1));
        printf("standard deviation is %f\n", stdev);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Opening of file stat_data.txt failed\n"); 
    }

    return 0;   
}
```

I'm trying to open the text file "stat_data" in Xcode and it works on a linux computer, but it doesn't seem to work on Xcode. I think there's something wrong with the settings but I don't know what it could be.

Screenshot of the IDE showing where the stat_data.txt is placed -
[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Are you sure the file `stat_data.txt` is placed in the same directory where the executable is generated?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is. I just added screenshot of my Xcode file so I think they're in the same directory.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but your test if `fp_in` is `NULL` is fishy. If `fp_in` is `NULL` you need to print an error message and abort the program.

Comment: @AzureYammy Actually the executable generate after compiling is not the same directory as the file. The source file (.c) is, but not the executable. The executable is actually in - `/User/James/Library/... .../Build/Products/Debug`. (You can see this path at the bottom of your SS in the logs) You can move the file there or use the absolute path for your `stat_data.txt`

Comment: _I'm pretty sure it is._ Well either the file __is__  there or it __is not__. Please check if the file is in the same directory as the executable and tell us if it is there or not.

Comment: include <errno.h> and print errno to see what is going on

Comment: When you have the value of `errno` the command line tool `perror` will tell you what the error means.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because the place where the Xcode created de binary file is different where your txt file is locate.

So I put my txt file in the same directory of my binary (readFile).
In the picture I list where my source and binary file are locate.

[image]

If you don't know where your binary file is. You can show it f you don't know where your binary file is. You can show it using the "show in finder".

[image]

So my result is it:
File opened.

[image]

Comment: Actually, it's nothing to do with the location of the binary. The main problem is that Xcode has set the working directory to some directory other than where the text file is.

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not specify a path to the file name when you open it, the program expects the file to be in the current working directory which is set by Xcode when you run the program in Xcode and set by the shell when you run the program from the command line (as the directoy you are in when you run it).

There are two ways to get around this:

- specify an absolute path when you open the file e.g.

  ```
  /Users/thiagmarques/path/to/stat_data.txt
  ```
- Edit the scheme to run from the directory containing the file. If you click on "Edit Scheme" and then select the Run section. The Options tab has a check box to "Use custom working directory". Check this and enter the directory containing your text file.